# Displaying sourcecode when clicking a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

First I have to let you know that i am a newbie in this area, learning from tutorials.

With that said I'm looking for a way to load sourcecode from the codebehind file into a textbox, when clicking a button. Same goes for the aspx file.

Im making this website, where i am going to show code examples from what im doing. So if I navigate to myweb.com/tutorial1done.aspx this page would show me the final result from the tutorial done. When i click the show source button it should make 2 textboxes visible, and add the codebehind to the first box, and the aspx source to the second box.

I don't know if it is possible, but I am hoping so.

This far i have this:

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DateTimeOutput.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.DateTimeOutput" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/codeformatter.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<customControls:Header runat="server" heading="Date and Time Output" />
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="outputText" runat="server" Height="175px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="runButton" runat="server" Text="Run Code" 
        onclick="runButton_Click" Width="95px" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="clearButton" runat="server" Text="Clear Console" 
        onclick="clearButton_Click" Width="95px" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="dt_showSource_btn" runat="server" 
        onclick="dt_showSource_btn_Click" Text="Show Source" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Label ID="dtLabel1" runat="server" Text="Code Behind:" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="dtcb_output" runat="server" Height="175px" 
    TextMode="MultiLine" Visible="False" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="dtLabel2" runat="server" Text="ASPX:" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="dtaspx_output" runat="server" Height="175px" 
    TextMode="MultiLine" Visible="False" Width="400px"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class DateTimeOutput : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void output(String value)
    {
        outputText.Text += value + Environment.NewLine;
    }

    protected void runButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        output(dt.ToString());
        DateTime nowDt = DateTime.Now;
        output(nowDt.ToString());
    }

    protected void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        outputText.Text = "";
    }

    protected void dt_showSource_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dtcb_output.Visible == false)
        {
            dtLabel1.Visible = true;
            dtcb_output.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dtLabel1.Visible = false;
            dtcb_output.Visible = false;
        }

        if (dtaspx_output.Visible == false)
        {
            dtLabel2.Visible = true;
            dtaspx_output.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dtLabel2.Visible = false;
            dtaspx_output.Visible = false;
        }

    }

}
}
```

For now source highlighting is not needed, unless its easy to do.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Not sure whether you mean some pre-defined source code or are you referring to source code for the current page?

Comment: I was referring to the source of the current page - But mattens answer tells me that it is not possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're refering to the actual code of your code behind file, you have a problem. As the file will be compiled and then be placed as intermediate code in a dynamic link library (.dll), you don't have access to the .aspx.cs file any more. The only way to go would be to include the code behind file with the deployd project and open it with a FileStream (or whatever) to read it and display it's content.

Comment: Well - i guess that would be the same as if i copied the .cs file to a .txt file and read that one? It was to make it easy for my self somehow - So I could have a function to use for all of my finished tutorials.

Comment: Somewhere in the build options you can specify a after-build script which can automatically copy the file to the right position (to the bin dir).

Comment: That seems to get a little too triggy for me, for now - im totally green on asp.net and visual studio.

Comment: There is no big clue... It's something like `cp $(ProjectDir)/folder/file.aspx.cs $(TargetDir)/file.aspx.cs` (see http://visualstudiohacks.com/general/customize-your-project-build-process/ for more help)!